# Rails 3.2: undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Getting the following error when implementing [this](https://github.com/watu/table_builder) calendar gem.

```
NoMethodError in Users#show

Showing /Users/nelsonkeating/Desktop/ReminDeal/app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #66 raised:

undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #66):

63:   </h2>
64:                 <%= calendar_for @friends, :year => @date.year, :month => @date.month do |calendar| %>
65:                  <%= calendar.head('mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun') %>
66:                   <%= calendar.day(:day_method => :dob) do |date, friends| %>
67:                    <%= date.day %>
68:                     <ul>
69:                         <% friends.each do |friend| %>
```

users_controller.rb

```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    authorize! :index, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])

  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @friends = @user.friends.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @date = params[:month] ? Date.parse(params[:month]) : Date.today
   end
```

users/show.html.erb

```
<div id="calendar">
    <h2 id="month">
    <%= link_to "<", :month => (@date.beginning_of_month-1).strftime("%Y-%m") %>
    <%=h @date.strftime("%B %Y") %>
    <%= link_to ">", :month => (@date.end_of_month+1).strftime("%Y-%m") %>
  </h2>
                <%= calendar_for @friends, :year => @date.year, :month => @date.month do |calendar| %>
                 <%= calendar.head('mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun') %>
                  <%= calendar.day(:day_method => :dob) do |date, friends| %>
                   <%= date.day %>
                    <ul>
                        <% friends.each do |friend| %>
                        <li> <%= link_to h(friend.name), friends %></li>
                     <% end %>
                    </ul>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
</div>
```

friend.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: friends
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  dob        :date
#  gender     :string(255)
#  user_id    :integer
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
#  int        :string(255)
#

class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :dob, :gender, :interests, :int, :interest_ids, :date
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :person_interests, :as => :person
  has_many :interests, :through => :person_interests
  serialize :ints
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `@date` defined in your show action.

Comment: i moved " @date = params[:month] ? Date.parse(params[:month]) : Date.today" to the show action and get the same exact error.

Comment: could it have to do with how my friends table is setup? I added the schema above

Comment: its the friend (of the user) that the calendar is rendering but yes, it does have a valid dob value.. im wondering if the dob column should be :datetime and not :date

Comment: Either make your dob column NOT NULL or handle nil values in your application. I'm pretty sure it's trying to iterate over a friend with a nil dob value.

Comment: just checked my db and your right.. for some reason my dob attribute is not saving

Comment: ok wait seems that the issue is the record is only saved if the date is before todays.. im just asking for day/month since it is someones birthday.. any idea?

Comment: or its just saving inconsistently in general.. got a future date to save